# Bitcoin price synchronized between exchanges

Tags: exchanges

how the different exchanges manage to have the price of Bitcoin synchronized (or at least very close)?

Comment: Arbitrage bots, mostly

Comment: May you explain in More detail the arbitrage bots?

Answer (score 3):

The exchanges don't need to synchronize.  It's just traders keeping the prices close.  If the price is $6500 on one exchange and $6700 on another for BTC.  Traders will sell on the $6700 exchange and buy on $6500 exchange until they are close.  They now own more BTC then before without spending any money

Comment: right, it's called arbitrage.